# React native Cone Shaped Button

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to make a cone-shaped button in React-Native. Something like this:

[Sorry I can't display images yet, but one of these sections.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beEi5.gif)

I've played around with TouchableOpacity and custom styled views inside, but it seems like the only way of doing so is with transparent borders that still register when pressed.

Is it possible to make a button in React-Native with the shape I'm looking for and also with the collision box to match?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
     <View style={{

                width: 0,
                height: 0,
                borderLeftWidth: 55,
                borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
                borderRightWidth: 55,
                borderRightColor: 'transparent',
                borderTopWidth: 100,
                borderTopColor: 'red',
                borderRadius: 55

     }}/>
```

and if you want more shapes you can have a look here https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native

Comment: I've seen this. The bounds for where a user can click on this still includes the transparent sections, though. I am looking to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be using SVG, there are some open source libraries out there which support both android and IOS.
for example with [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) you can do it like this:

```
import SVG, {Path} from 'react-native-svg'
// the rest of requirements
// in the render method:
<View style={{flex: 1, alignContent: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  <Svg width={60} height={60} viewBox='0 0 15.875 15.875'>
    <Path d='M15.875 0A15.875 15.875 0 0 0 0 15.875h15.968V.005A15.875 15.875 0 0 0 15.875 0z' fill='#ff3333' />
  </Svg>
</View>
```

you may wrap this shape with your favorite touch component.

please follow the repo documentation to install the library properly.